# OP Amp non-inverter amplifier - Do I have to use power supply to amplify a signal?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Im new to OP-AMPs I simulate a circuit using one op amp just to amplify the signal to the double this is my diagram [image]

But im not sure if the Vs+ and the Vs- is useful in this case? I put the Vs+ to 5v and Vs- to GND and also remove it and it gave me the same result, did it matter if its or not connected?

Comment: The top connection on the op-amp is the positive power supply (Vs+?), the bottom one is for ground. You seem to have them connected backwards. (Without knowing how you're simulating this, maybe your simulator just ignores the op-amp's power connections)

Comment: Also why do you have the non-inverting input connected to Vcc?

Comment: I just want to amplify a 5v Signal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an extremely messy drawing. Try redrawing it with less branches, it will be easier to read when you use rails for the power (Vcc and ground) nets.

Like Matt says: yes, opamps need a power supply. But your circuit can't work, even with the power supply. It's a noninverting amplifier, and the output voltage is defined as

$$ V_{out} = \dfrac{R1 + R2}{R2} \cdot V_+ $$

That would be

$$ V_{out} = 2 \cdot V_+ $$

Now \$V_+\$ is your positive power supply, and the output voltage should be twice that. That's impossible. The 5V supply voltage is the maximum you can get, the opamp can't pull 10V out of thin air.

Answer (score 2):

First, get rid of those awful DMM blocks, and put in measurement probes. It's a lot cleaner and easier to look at. As for he question itself, yes, power supplies are required. You can't get a higher voltage without deriving it from some higher voltage. (Actually, you can, but that is beyond the scope of this question.) The fact it works without power connected means that component model is garbage, and that kind of surprises me coming from Multisim.

Comment: So if I manage positive signals, can I only connect Vs+ and Vs- to gnd? in my case Vs+=10V is enough to duplicate the signal? If I connect Vs+=7v Ill only be able to get at Max 7v?

Comment: How model behaves close to the rails depends on how faithfully it follows datasheet parameters.